# не считывает команду doExit и метод мейн заканчивается после printIf. все скобки, вроде все в порядке) В чем проблема?

Tags: java

public class Main {

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuessNumber();
    printIf();
    
  
}
while(true){
    printIf();
    switch (in.nextLine()) {
        case "yes":
            GuessNumber();
        case "no":
            doExit(in.nextLine());
        default:
            System.out.println("Try again!");
    }
}





public static void printIf(){
        System.out.println("\nHi Buddy, let's play!");
        System.out.println("1.Yes");
        System.out.println("2.No");

    }


    public static void GuessNumber() {
        System.out.println("Let's start. Guess number from 0 to 9! You have 3 tries!");
        int maxTry = 3;
        int userAnswer = 0;
        for (int countTry = 1; countTry < maxTry; countTry++) ;
        int number = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        while (true) {
            if (number > userAnswer) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is low");
            } else if (number < userAnswer) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is high");

            } else (number = userAnswer) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations!");
            }
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте пожалуйста

Уберите скобку перед while и добавьте после цикла

```
else (number = userAnswer)
```

На

```
else if (number == userAnswer)
```

Comment: даже на else if (number `==` userAnswer)